# How to get "elements" in node

Tags: c#, xml

I trying to get "elements" from node and show in MessageBox

My XML: `<Item Name="Test" Count="5"/>`

Elements:

> ```
> Name
> Count
> ```

My Code:

```
XmlNodeList xmlNodes = xmlDocument.SelectNodes("Item");
                            foreach (XmlNode xmlNode in xmlNodes)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show(xmlNode.InnerText);
                            }
```

But I do not know how to do this

Comment: Name and count are not elements, those are attributes of the Item element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use Attributes. Check my solution

```
XmlNodeList xmlNodes = xmlDocument.SelectNodes("Item");
foreach (XmlNode xmlNode in xmlNodes)
{
    foreach (XmlAttribute attr in xmlNodes.Attributes)
    {
         MessageBox.Show($"Attribute Name is {attr.Name} and Value is {attr.Value}");
    }
}
```